# Why is the regex for range [001-180] not working?

Tags: regex

regex for the range [001-180] for a flex ( .l extension) program.

I am trying a lexical analysis aka flex program to accept all inputs within a range [001-180].
I have tried this:

```
0[0-9][1-9]|0[1-9]0|1[0-7][0-9]|180
```

But it is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Add word boundaries around the whole thing so it won't match the range inside another number.

```
\b(?:0[0-9][1-9]|0[1-9]0|1[0-7][0-9]|180)\b
```